# Android StrikeThrough span not working on spaces

Tags: android, spannablestring, strikethrough

Better I put my question as an example

I have the word FREE in a textview
I apply a strikethrough(EXC, EXC) span to the word FREE so I get <strike>FREE</strike>
Then I insert spaces between the letters and here comes the problem, because I get 
<strike>F</strike> <strike>R</strike> <strike>E</strike> <strike>E</strike> but I want <strike>F R E E</strike>
It seems it only happens with spaces(I also tried "\u00a0"), because I also tried to insert a normal character (L) and there was no problem, the result was <strike>FLRLELE</strike> and not <strike>F</strike>L<strike>R</strike>L<strike>E</strike>L<strike>E</strike>.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: seems like a good reason for making a custom span since StrikeThroughSpan cannot be customized to strike-through-spaces

Answer (score 0):

Are you applying the span character by character, or to the entire substring?

I was having the same problem when I tried the former approach; but when I changed to the latter, it worked perfectly.

### [image: Image Of Result]

Here is an excerpt of the code I used.

The if conditions add a padding of strikethrough around the substrings.

```
    //  ↑↑↑  Several layers of loops...  :-X

    mySubString = textview_Text.substring ( indexStart, indexEnd );

    for ( Integer charIndex = 0 ; charIndex < mySubString.length() ; charIndex++ )
        {
            charOfIndex = String.valueOf ( mySubString.charAt ( charIndex ) );

            if ( charIndex > 0 )
                { charOfIndex_Previous = String.valueOf ( mySubString.charAt ( charIndex - 1 ) ); }
            else
                { charOfIndex_Previous = charOfIndex; }

            if ( charIndex < mySubString.length() - 1 )
                { charOfIndex_Next = String.valueOf ( mySubString.charAt ( charIndex + 1 ) ); }
            else
                { charOfIndex_Next = charOfIndex; }

            if ( ( charOfIndex.equals ( charSpace ) )
            && ( ! charOfIndex_Next.equals ( charSpace ) ) )
                { spanStart = indexFromPreviousLoop + charIndex; }

            if ( ( ! charOfIndex_Previous.equals ( charSpace ) )
            && ( charOfIndex.equals ( charSpace ) ) )
                { spanEnd = indexFromPreviousLoop + charIndex + 1; }
        }

    mySpannable.setSpan ( new StrikethroughSpan (), spanStart, spanEnd, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE );
```